# How Many Tables Does Magento 2 Have?

Tags: magento2, database

Can You Please Tell Me How Many Tables Does Magento 2 Have? 
In MY Database Its Only showing 250. I was installing Magento 2. Its been stucked at 73% since last 20min!

```
Module 'Magento_GroupedProductSampleData':Installing data...
```

is there everything okay or not!!!

Answer (score 1):

In default Magento, there are approx. 315 tables, if all default modules have been installed.

If you are unable to install Magento 2 from the browser, you can use the command-line method to install Magento.

The format of the install command follows:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --<option>=<value> ... --<option>=<value>
```

For example:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password=root --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
```

Before every option, prepend double hyphens (-).

Please let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Latest Default Magento have 356 tables in database.**

As  per your stuck you can remove your database and try again to install setup.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Usually Magento 2 have 399 to 329 default tables based on differ versions.

I have faced same issue, but after few minutes, in your case 20 mins. It was working.

Try to load your `front-end` it will be redirected to `<your_url>l` , means there will be a **"l"** appended to url.

Then goto `core_config_data` and **fix  site url**. And remove `var/cache` folder.

Now run your site it will be working.

Not sure why magento(espl in 2.2.6) stuck always but after few minutes I found it's installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I have currently installed magento 2.2.5 community there are 356 default db tables. Which client you are using for db, i am using phpmyadmin for mysql and i can check all tables.

Answer (score 0):

**That's true**. And Magento 2.3 has 250 tables as per the latest installation.

Sometimes sample data takes little bit more time to install.